# How to work around Fontdeck giving different font families for one font?

Tags: css, font-face, font-family, webfont-loader

Fontdeck doesn't offer an option to host files yourself, and unfortunately the CSS it returns has different font families for different variations of the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Apercu Pro Light';
    src: ...;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Apercu Pro Bold Italic';
    src:...;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Apercu Pro Regular';
    src: null;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This is highly inconvenient, especially given that they already *know* correct weight and style.   Can I work around this and still use `Apercu` as `font-family` in my CSS and have browser figure out which font to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Fontdeck suggests to use [webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) to load fonts, we can listen to its events and rewrite the inline `<style>` tag it appends as soon as it is available:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var hasRewrittenRules = false;

  /**
   * Fontdeck returns different font-family for each font variation.
   * We will rewrite inline <style> it creates to have one font-family.
   */
  function rewriteFontFaceRules() {
    if (hasRewrittenRules) {
      return;
    }

    var key,
        sheet,
        index,
        rule,
        fontFamily;

    for (key in document.styleSheets) {
      sheet = document.styleSheets[key];
      if (!sheet.ownerNode || sheet.ownerNode.tagName !== 'STYLE') {
        continue;
      }

      for (index in sheet.rules) {
        rule = sheet.rules[index];
        if (!(rule instanceof window.CSSFontFaceRule)) {
          continue;
        }

        fontFamily = rule.style.fontFamily;

        // CHANGE REWRITING RULES HERE:

        if (fontFamily && fontFamily.indexOf('Apercu') > -1 && fontFamily !== 'Apercu') {
          rule.style.fontFamily = 'Apercu';
          hasRewrittenRules = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  window.WebFontConfig = {
    fontdeck: { id: /* YOUR FONT ID */ },
    fontactive: rewriteFontFaceRules,
    active: rewriteFontFaceRules
  };

  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = ('https:' === document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
  '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
})();
```